# Why Math.random doesn't work at my code?

Tags: javascript, function

This is my lift program. But Math random doesn't work.

```
var person = {
     name: "Gorg",
     position: 2,
     goal: 9
 };
 var lift = {
     position: function() {
         var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
     }
 };
 console.log("Ok, buddy! You are at " + person.position + " floor");
 console.log("Lift is at " + lift.position + " floor");

 if (lift.position != person.position) {
     console.log("Please wait a minute, lift's coming");
 } 
 else {
     console.log("Lift is here. Please enter!");
 }

 if (lift.position > person.position) {
     for (i = person.position; i <= lift.position; i++) {
         console.log(i);
     }
 } 
 else if (lift.position < person.position) {
     for (i = person.position; i >= lift.position; --i) {
         console.log(i);
     }
 }  
 else {
     console.log("You're already at this level");
 }

 if (lift.position !== person.position) {
     if (person.goal > person.position) {
         for (i = person.position; i <= person.goal; i++) {
             console.log(i);
         }
     } 
     else if (person.goal < person.position) {
         for (i = person.position; i >= person.goal; --i) {
             console.log(i);
         }
     } 
     else {
         console.log("You're already at this level");
     }
 }
 console.log("Congratulation! You achieve your goal!");
```

Comment: What does "doesn't work" means? Please give examples what you expect and what is your result.

Comment: Also this doesn't work correct. It all time write first statement
if (lift.position() != person.position) {
     console.log("Please wait a minute, lift's coming");
 } 
 else {
     console.log("Lift is here. Please enter!");
What's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Two problems

First, change your `lift.position` function so that it **returns** the value (rather than assign it to an inaccessible local variable).

```
position: function() {
  return Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
}
```

Second, make sure you **call** the `lift.position()` function (use parentheses to call a function)...

```
lift.position()
```

Comment: Thank you! And can you help me one more time? 
if (lift.position() != person.position) {
 console.log("Please wait a minute, lift's coming"); 
}
 else { console.log("Lift is here. Please enter!");
 } 
It always write first sattement :(

Comment: Are you sure it **always** logs first statement?  Or does it just log first statement on average 9 out of 10 times?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var person = {
      name: "Gorg",
      position: 2,
      goal: 9
    };
    var lift = {
        position : function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x;

      }  
    }; 
    console.log("Ok, buddy! You are at " + person.position + " floor");
    console.log("Lift is at " + lift.position() + " floor");

    if (lift.position != person.position) {
    console.log("Please wait a minute, lift's coming");
    }
    else {
    console.log("Lift is here. Please enter!");
    }

    if (lift.position > person.position) {
     for (i = person.position; i <= lift.position; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    } else if (lift.position < person.position ) {
      for (i = person.position; i >= lift.position; --i) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    } else {
      console.log("You're already at this level");
    }

    if (lift.position !== person.position) {
      if (person.goal > person.position) {
       for (i = person.position; i <= person.goal; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    } else if (person.goal < person.position ) {
      for (i = person.position; i >= person.goal; --i) {
        console.log(i);
    }
    } else {
      console.log("You're already at this level");
    }
    }
    console.log("Congratulation! You achieve your goal!");
```

From what I could understand, this is the solution

```
//returned x here;
var lift = {
        position : function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x;

      }
```

//corrected the call to lift.position as lift.position()

`console.log("Lift is at " + lift.position() + " floor");`

Answer (score 0):

You have assigned a function to position property of the 
person object. To invoke the method you need to call function, ie lift.position() not lift.position. It will be better if you change the name of the property from "position" to "getPosition".

Comment: Thank you! And can you help me one more time?

if (lift.position() != person.position) {
     console.log("Please wait a minute, lift's coming");
 } 
 else {
     console.log("Lift is here. Please enter!");
 }
It always write first sattement :(

Comment: Update var lift = {
        position : function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x;
to 
var lift = {
        position : function() {
        var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
    return x;

      } ()

      }
Its happening because every time you check the condition, it calls random function again and updates lift position.